# Hide comment notification number and buttons in wp backend

Tags: php

Is there any hooks or tricks in wordpress to hide comment notification red alert in wordpress Comments tab from backend?
Check screenshot
[image]

This is author's dashboard.

I also want to remove and show only numbers associated to author's post from All, Pending, Approved and  so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code. remove totally comment functionality in backed.

Put this code in your current theme function.php file.

```
<?php
// Removes from admin menu
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_admin_menus' );
function my_remove_admin_menus() {
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
}
// Removes from post and pages
add_action('init', 'remove_comment_support', 100);

function remove_comment_support() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'comments' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'comments' );
}
// Removes from admin bar
function mytheme_admin_bar_render() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'mytheme_admin_bar_render' );
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't want to remove but want to show only list of those comments which are related to my post if i am a author.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your functions.php. it checks to see if the user is an admin or can moderate other users posts.

[Reference is here from WP Forum:](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/restricting-users-to-seeing-only-comments-on-their-posts-in-admin/)

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------
* Ensure that non-admins can see and manage only their own comments
*/ ------------------------------------------------------------

function myplugin_get_comment_list_by_user($clauses) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        global $user_ID, $wpdb;
        $clauses['join'] = ", wp_posts";
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND wp_posts.post_author = ".$user_ID." AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID";
    };
    return $clauses;
};
// ensure that editors and admins can moderate everything
if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
add_filter('comments_clauses', 'myplugin_get_comment_list_by_user');
}
```

However $wpdb is a very powerful tool and runs to your Database. You could use the function below: it works in similar way as above by check if the user can edit others posts or is an admin. Otherwise it returns only their posts.
[Reference: From wpbeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-limit-authors-to-their-own-posts-in-wordpress-admin/) 
    function posts_for_current_author($query) {
        global $pagenow;

```
    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author', $user_ID );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

Comment: Yes, But I already managed to show only comments associated to my posts. But now i want to show like Mine(2) but not like All(5) | Pending(1)|Trash(2) and such options in listing page in backend